# Making only part of a label bold while using geom_label_repel() in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I have a dataset:

```
> dput(df.inn3)
structure(list(PC1 = c(-0.148688238177717, -0.908694225222203, 
1.15048295817949, -0.403789747957251, 0.785402066942118), PC2 = c(0.371103940258495, 
-1.20385188925406, -0.357165542408208, 0.707690895976991, -0.447999850097107
), distances = c(0.399782849366721, 1.50830519664051, 1.20464860508996, 
0.814783753399696, 0.904190396124612), label = c("<b>Innovation need:</b>  Improving\ncharacterization of\nnon-traditional anglers", 
"<b>Innovation need:</b>  Improving\nefficiency", "<b>Innovation need:</b>  Gathering\nself-reporting recreational data", 
"<b>Innovation need:</b>  Improving\ncharacterization of preferences\nand behaviors", 
"<b>Innovation need:</b>  Using emerging\ntechnology")), row.names = c("Innovation need: Improving\ncharacterization of\nnon-traditional anglers", 
"Innovation need: Improving\nefficiency", "Innovation need: Gathering\nself-reporting recreational data", 
"Innovation need: Improving\ncharacterization of preferences\nand behaviors", 
"Innovation need: Using emerging\ntechnology"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df.imm3)
structure(list(PC1 = c(-1.23590280262104, 0.201388002767894, 
0.914977218413494, 0.126721368707057, 0.0872621215582316, 0.204537959161584
), PC2 = c(0.840721410891728, 0.0708437839704083, 1.18262760256924, 
-0.323000400083109, -0.353599966664034, 0.00713742281189857), 
    distances = c(1.49474687765465, 0.213485290795612, 1.49525628457946, 
    0.34696911064364, 0.364208201834678, 0.204662452693164), 
    label = c("<b>Import:</b>  Characterizing angler\npreferences and behaviors", 
    "<b>Import:</b>  Improving public\ninterface", "<b>Import:</b>  Making management\ndecisions", 
    "<b>Import:</b>  Measuring fishery\nperformance", "<b>Import:</b>  Monitoring species of\nconcern", 
    "<b>Import:</b>  Measuring exploitation")), row.names = c("Import: Characterizing angler\npreferences and behaviors", 
"Import: Improving public\ninterface", "Import: Making management\ndecisions", 
"Import: Measuring fishery\nperformance", "Import: Monitoring species of\nconcern", 
"Import: Measuring exploitation"), class = "data.frame")
> dput(df.pca)
structure(list(PC1 = c(-0.0141206273717713, -0.209463263804952, 
0.0074598774923903, 0.197873115466226, -0.0201814499150566, 0.197873115466226, 
-0.0815799733773477, -0.0488464843658022, -0.209463263804952, 
0.20544862737961, 0.197873115466226, -0.0141206273717715, -0.00654511545838752, 
0.00745987749238988, -0.209463263804952, -0.00654511545838752, 
-0.209463263804952, -0.0488464843658022, -0.209463263804952, 
0.12776765600661, 0.197873115466226, -0.0488464843658022, -0.0488464843658022, 
-0.0488464843658022, -0.25819411374976, -0.0114745139177322, 
-0.0488464843658022, 0.197873115466226, -0.209463263804952, -0.229529079299015, 
-0.209463263804952, -0.0141206273717715, -0.0114745139177322, 
-0.0141206273717715, 0.197873115466226, 0.197873115466226, 0.197873115466226, 
-0.209463263804952, 1.60010997514765e-05, -0.0141206273717715, 
-0.209463263804952, 0.12776765600661, 0.116408776509872, -0.209463263804952, 
-0.0141206273717715, -0.209463263804952, -0.0488464843658022, 
0.100245741207939, 0.197873115466226, 0.32575640589383, -0.0488464843658022, 
-0.0141206273717715, 0.32575640589383, 0.12776765600661, -0.00757173372560303, 
0.12776765600661, -0.25819411374976, 0.32575640589383, -0.0488464843658022, 
-0.209463263804952, -0.0488464843658022, -0.209463263804952, 
-0.0890360726819566, -0.216919363109561, 0.32575640589383, -0.0488464843658022, 
0.197873115466226, -0.0114745139177322, -0.00757173372560303, 
-0.00757173372560303, -0.0141206273717715, -0.209463263804952, 
-0.209463263804952, 0.197873115466226, 0.12776765600661, 0.197873115466226, 
0.32575640589383, -0.209463263804952, -0.0488464843658022, -0.130310823322156, 
0.116408776509872, -0.0815799733773477, -0.25819411374976, -0.0114745139177322, 
-0.0488464843658022, -0.0815799733773477, -0.209463263804952, 
0.32575640589383, 0.32575640589383, -0.229529079299015, -0.22346825675573, 
0.32575640589383, 0.197873115466226, -0.095584966328125, -0.209463263804952, 
-0.0488464843658022, -0.229529079299015, -0.0628514773165796, 
0.12776765600661, 0.12776765600661, 0.32575640589383, 0.12776765600661, 
-0.209463263804952, 0.32575640589383, -0.252832989072648, 0.033235578332924, 
-0.0135684775992678, -0.252832989072647, -0.270045628592021, 
-0.252832989072647, 0.229914762652247, -0.252832989072647, -0.00953344360972124, 
-0.253016683861236, -0.0305974223300524, -0.236943656174202, 
0.245804095550691, 0.00250455008776582, -0.00724164915480696, 
-0.0145153991165325, -0.254156295693576, 0.229731067863658, 0.245804095550691, 
-0.252832989072647, -0.208038044199645, -0.00971713839831004, 
-0.252832989072647, -0.0265521344527103, -0.00953344360972124, 
-0.252832989072647, -0.00724164915480696, -0.00724164915480696, 
-0.00953344360972124, -0.0135684775992677, 0.27653512379585, 
-0.00339030995384935, 0.274893402313837, 0.014381217331538, 0.230069918824527, 
-0.27004562859202, 0.290782735212282, 0.274893402313837, 0.229914762652247, 
-0.00953344360972124, -0.252832989072647, -0.00724164915480696, 
0.0330518835443355, -0.0139271145620746, 0.00250455008776582, 
-0.283212980234052, 0.229731067863658, -0.252832989072647, 0.253425691999773, 
-0.0265521344527103, 0.228591456031318, 0.274893402313837, -0.0145153991165325, 
-0.00724164915480696, -0.0267460831290948, -0.00724164915480696, 
0.27653512379585, 0.274893402313837, -0.252832989072647, -0.191965016512612, 
-0.00724164915480696, -0.00953344360972124, 0.00250455008776582, 
-0.00953344360972124, -0.00953344360972124, 0.00635588928872343, 
-0.252832989072647, -0.252832989072647, -0.00724164915480696, 
-0.252832989072647, 0.27653512379585, 0.0315938568509116, 0.27653512379585, 
-0.00724164915480696, 0.0354451960518692, -0.00953344360972124, 
0.229914762652247, 0.229914762652247, 0.0315938568509116, -0.190323295030599, 
0.212702123132873, -0.252832989072647, 0.037086917533882, -0.252832989072647, 
0.0474831897493562, -0.27004562859202, 0.0354451960518692, 0.0354451960518692, 
-0.00953344360972124, -0.00953344360972124, 0.229914762652247, 
0.229914762652247, 0.0302705502299826, 0.27653512379585, 0.00250455008776582, 
0.245804095550691, -0.252832989072647, 0.229914762652247, -0.236943656174202, 
-0.0147080894316077, 0.228591456031318, -0.00953344360972124, 
-0.0265521344527103), PC2 = c(0.203829248209386, -0.127203726947651, 
0.147296661133637, 0.00171278711832731, 0.101864889975649, 0.00171278711832772, 
-0.251127222987841, 0.286980948313469, -0.127203726947651, 0.0329199061713358, 
0.00171278711832778, 0.203829248209385, 0.235036367262393, 0.147296661133638, 
-0.127203726947651, 0.235036367262393, -0.127203726947651, 0.286980948313469, 
-0.127203726947651, -0.00783395395956061, 0.00171278711832778, 
0.286980948313469, 0.286980948313469, 0.286980948313469, 0.0436876792851882, 
-0.241580481909953, 0.286980948313469, 0.00171278711832778, -0.127203726947651, 
-0.141428379052632, -0.127203726947651, 0.203829248209385, -0.241580481909953, 
0.203829248209385, 0.00171278711832778, 0.00171278711832778, 
0.00171278711832778, -0.127203726947651, 0.120779035400652, 0.203829248209385, 
-0.127203726947651, -0.00783395395956061, -0.365503977950143, 
-0.127203726947651, 0.203829248209385, -0.127203726947651, 0.286980948313469, 
-0.0250981765713009, 0.00171278711832778, -0.122210708921862, 
0.286980948313469, 0.203829248209385, -0.122210708921862, -0.00783395395956061, 
0.11304997157387, -0.00783395395956061, 0.0436876792851882, -0.122210708921862, 
0.286980948313469, -0.127203726947651, 0.286980948313469, -0.127203726947651, 
-0.2541667934946, -0.13024329745441, -0.122210708921862, 0.286980948313469, 
0.00171278711832778, -0.241580481909953, 0.11304997157387, 0.11304997157387, 
0.203829248209385, -0.127203726947651, -0.127203726947651, 0.00171278711832778, 
-0.00783395395956061, 0.00171278711832778, -0.122210708921862, 
-0.127203726947651, 0.286980948313469, -0.080235816755002, -0.365503977950143, 
-0.251127222987841, 0.0436876792851882, -0.241580481909953, 0.286980948313469, 
-0.251127222987841, -0.127203726947651, -0.122210708921862, -0.122210708921862, 
-0.141428379052632, -0.0394640208188951, -0.122210708921862, 
0.00171278711832778, -0.163387516859085, -0.127203726947651, 
0.286980948313469, -0.141428379052632, 0.374720654442225, -0.00783395395956061, 
-0.00783395395956061, -0.122210708921862, -0.00783395395956061, 
-0.127203726947651, -0.122210708921862, 0.0512592612275564, -0.177101873096904, 
-0.189260764541249, 0.0512592612275568, 0.0184432352823786, 0.0512592612275568, 
0.0537506715078537, 0.0512592612275567, 0.291291955043046, 0.0482805189939425, 
-0.219098048252813, -0.0276564079786102, -0.0251649976983132, 
-0.265197691513802, -0.270848502252605, -0.201352649568953, -0.0604724339237883, 
0.0507719292742395, -0.0251649976983132, 0.0512592612275567, 
0.0426706239725855, 0.288313212809431, 0.0512592612275567, -0.210164910991586, 
0.291291955043046, 0.0512592612275567, -0.270848502252605, -0.270848502252605, 
0.291291955043046, -0.189260764541249, 0.0629308207185855, 0.206725475098076, 
0.0481407764864968, -0.22470794327417, 0.0206426883617808, 0.0184432352823787, 
-0.0307748927196702, 0.0481407764864968, 0.0537506715078538, 
0.291291955043046, 0.0512592612275567, -0.270848502252605, -0.180080615330518, 
-0.193524726701002, -0.265197691513802, -0.00543965340157225, 
0.0507719292742395, 0.0512592612275567, -0.0311077656380111, 
-0.210164910991586, -0.0579810236434912, 0.0481407764864968, 
-0.201352649568953, -0.270848502252605, 0.258475929097868, -0.270848502252605, 
0.0629308207185855, 0.0481407764864968, 0.0512592612275567, -0.0332663029999672, 
-0.270848502252605, 0.291291955043046, -0.265197691513802, 0.291291955043046, 
0.291291955043046, 0.212376285836879, 0.0512592612275567, 0.0512592612275567, 
-0.270848502252605, 0.0512592612275567, 0.0629308207185855, -0.191891917328992, 
0.0629308207185855, -0.270848502252605, 0.285682060021689, 0.291291955043046, 
0.0537506715078538, 0.0537506715078538, -0.191891917328992, -0.0184762587678785, 
0.0209346455626758, 0.0512592612275567, 0.300472104253777, 0.0512592612275567, 
-0.270807586535159, 0.0184432352823787, 0.285682060021689, 0.285682060021689, 
0.291291955043046, 0.291291955043046, 0.0537506715078538, 0.0537506715078538, 
-0.303623612480337, 0.0629308207185855, -0.265197691513802, -0.0251649976983132, 
0.0512592612275567, 0.0537506715078538, -0.0276564079786102, 
-0.29801371745898, -0.0579810236434912, 0.291291955043046, -0.210164910991586
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
"39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
"50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", 
"61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", 
"72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", 
"83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", 
"94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", 
"104", "sit1", "sit2", "sit3", "sit4", "sit5", "sit6", "sit7", 
"sit8", "sit9", "sit10", "sit11", "sit12", "sit13", "sit14", 
"sit15", "sit16", "sit17", "sit18", "sit19", "sit20", "sit21", 
"sit22", "sit23", "sit24", "sit25", "sit26", "sit27", "sit28", 
"sit29", "sit30", "sit31", "sit32", "sit33", "sit34", "sit35", 
"sit36", "sit37", "sit38", "sit39", "sit40", "sit41", "sit42", 
"sit43", "sit44", "sit45", "sit46", "sit47", "sit48", "sit49", 
"sit50", "sit51", "sit52", "sit53", "sit54", "sit55", "sit56", 
"sit57", "sit58", "sit59", "sit60", "sit61", "sit62", "sit63", 
"sit64", "sit65", "sit66", "sit67", "sit68", "sit69", "sit70", 
"sit71", "sit72", "sit73", "sit74", "sit75", "sit76", "sit77", 
"sit78", "sit79", "sit80", "sit81", "sit82", "sit83", "sit84", 
"sit85", "sit86", "sit87", "sit88", "sit89", "sit90", "sit91", 
"sit92", "sit93", "sit94", "sit95", "sit96", "sit97", "sit98", 
"sit99", "sit100", "sit101", "sit102", "sit103"))
```

I am trying to label just "Import:" and "Innovation need:" as bold so that they show up in the label in bold for each label inserted into `geom_label_repel().` I tried to do this with HTML code:

```
df.imm3$label <- gsub("Import:", "<b>Import:</b> ", rownames(df.imm3))
df.inn3$label <- gsub("Innovation need:", "<b>Innovation need:</b> ", rownames(df.inn3))

# Generate the plot
pc.plot <- ggplot(df.rda, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, color = group, fill = group),
               data = hull, alpha = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dodgerblue4", "#56B4E9", "orange", "#D94801",
                               "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#67001F")) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = group, color = group),
               data = hull, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3, color = "grey20") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("dodgerblue4", "#56B4E9", "orange", "#D94801",
                                "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#67001F")) +
  geom_segment(data = df.imm3, aes(x = 0, xend = PC1, y = 0, yend = PC2), 
               color = "#08306B", size = 0.75, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"))) +
  geom_segment(data = df.inn3, aes(x = 0, xend = PC1, y = 0, yend = PC2), 
               color = "#3F007D", size = 0.75, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"))) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df.imm3, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = label),
                   color = "#08306B", size = 4, alpha = 0.7, parse = T) +
  geom_label_repel(data = df.inn3, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = label),
                   color = "#3F007D", size = 4, alpha = 0.7, parse = T)
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
Error in `geom_label_repel()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 8th layer.
Caused by error in `parse()`:
! <text>:1:1: unexpected '<'
1: <
    ^
```

I can get it to run if I take out the `parse=T` argument in `geom_label_repel()` but then my plots look like this:
[image]

How can I make a label in `ggplot` with `geom_label_repel()` so that only the sections I want in the label are in bold? I'd also like to keep the text left aligned too instead of center aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parse=TRUE` only allows to parse math expressions which use `?plotmath` notation.

Formatting using HTML, CSS or markdown is only supported when using so-called rich text as provided by the `gridtext` package. Unfortunately, as to the best of my knowledge `ggrepel` does not support rich text as of the moment.

Hence, if you want to use `ggrepel` and format only some of the words you have to use `?plotmath` which requires slightly more effort to make your labels proper `plotmath` expressions. Additionally, note that `plotmath` does not allow for line-breaks but we can fake one using `atop`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

df.imm3$label <- gsub("Import:", "bold('Import:')", rownames(df.imm3))
df.inn3$label <- gsub("Innovation need:", "bold('Innovation need:')", rownames(df.inn3))

df.imm3$label <- gsub(" ", "~", df.imm3$label)
df.inn3$label <- gsub(" ", "~", df.inn3$label)
df.imm3$label <- gsub("^(.*?)\\n(.*)$", "atop(\\1, \\2)", df.imm3$label)
df.inn3$label <- gsub("(.*?)\\n(.*)$", "atop(\\1, \\2)", df.inn3$label)
df.inn3$label <- gsub("\\n", "~", df.inn3$label)


ggplot(df.pca, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dotted") +
  coord_fixed() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) +
  # geom_polygon(aes(group = group, color = group, fill = group),
  #   data = hull, alpha = 0.2
  # ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(
    "dodgerblue4", "#56B4E9", "orange", "#D94801",
    "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#67001F"
  ), aesthetics = c("fill", "color")) +
  # geom_polygon(aes(group = group, fill = group, color = group),
  #   data = hull, alpha = 0.4
  # ) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.3, color = "grey20") +
  geom_segment(
    data = df.imm3, aes(x = 0, xend = PC1, y = 0, yend = PC2),
    color = "#08306B", size = 0.75, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"))
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = df.inn3, aes(x = 0, xend = PC1, y = 0, yend = PC2),
    color = "#3F007D", size = 0.75, arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.01, "npc"))
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = df.imm3, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = label),
    color = "#08306B", size = 4, alpha = 0.7, parse = TRUE
  ) +
  geom_label_repel(
    data = df.inn3, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, label = label),
    color = "#3F007D", size = 4, alpha = 0.7, parse = TRUE
  )
```

[image]